# Unexpected error - Axios can not read properties

Tags: laravel, axios

for a real time project i use laravel 8 and axios javascript  library used to make HTTP requests.
the backend work great .
for example if go to this URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users`the following data will be show

`[{"id":1,"name":"Hossein Khosromanesh","email":"test@gmail.com","email_verified_at":null,"created_at":"2022-01-22T19:52:12.000000Z","updated_at":"2022-01-22T19:52:12.000000Z"}]`

the problem comes when i want to show the data to the frontend , we got error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get') at users:84:18`

actually `get('/api/users')` from `window.axios.get('/api/users')` is the main problem

the front end code :

```
<script>
    
    window.axios.get('/api/users')
        .then((response) => {
            const usersElement = document.getElementById('users')
            let users = response.data
            users.ForEach((user,index) => {
                let element = document.createElement('li')
                element.setAttribute('id' , user.id)
                element.innerText = user.name
    
                usersElement.appendChild(element)
    
            })
    
        })
    
    </script>
```

what's wrong was my code ? can somebody please help me and free me from darkness : )

Comment: Could you please add your front end code here

Comment: @Dolar yes of course , i just edited and insert more information to question

Comment: The error is telling you that the method you're invoking (`get`) doesn't exist because its parent (`window.axios`) is undefined. So, why do you think axios is contained inside the `window` object?

Comment: @samuei i required loadlash and axios in app.js file in resources directory 
`window._ = require('lodash');`
`window.axios = require('axios');`

Answer (score 1):

If you are importing axios using a script tag in your html or blade file, you can use it with `axios.get` instead of `window.axios.get`.

Comment: sorry bro i used that but problem still exist

Answer (score 0):

As per My understanding from your code. You have to import axios in vue component or view where you consume API like below.

```
import axios from "axios";
```

Then You can use it like

```
axios.get('/api/users').then();
```

**Note:-** No need to register axios inside windows object in app.js for more information please refer below link

https://axios-http.com/docs/intro

If above method still not work for you then follow below step

**Take backup of your code first then perform below step**

1. Check your package.json file and verify axios is present over there or not.
2. If you don't find then install it using npm command
3. If you find then delete your package.lock.json file and run npm install command
4. Then follow import step mentioned above and try.

Answer (score 0):

if you are following  the (JuanD MeGon RealTime Course) make sure the( app.js file)  is already loaded (does not contain the word defer)

```
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" ></script>
```